# using wildcards inside mapping functions python

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

Is their a way to use a wildcard in your mapping function. I have something like this:

```
dictionary = {'James':'James Mcree'}
```

basically stating that anywhere it finds a James in my data frame it changes the names to James Mcree but I would somehow like to throw a wildcard into my mapping function like such:

```
dictionary = {'Jam*':'James Mcree'}
```

So it would look in my data frame and anywhere it had the starting letters Jam* it would change it to James Mcree. So it wouldnt matter what comes after Jam. It could be Jammed, Jamis..etc I just want to use the wildcard to say if it has these letters change it to the name specified.

If I am understandign correctly the asterik represents anything from this point on change to designated name which is James Mcree.

Furthermore if you are able to do this is their also a way to specify something like this:

```
dictionary = {'J*s':'James Mcree'}
```

so it would look for anything that starts with J and ends with s.

I havent found a way to do this any help would be great, thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a regular expression be used as a key in a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343680/can-a-regular-expression-be-used-as-a-key-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: You probably want a function that handles that logic.  `lambda x: if x.startswith('Jam') or (x.startswith('J') and x.endswith('s')): return 'James Mcree' ...`  Then when you call `map` you would apply this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using RegEx's:

Demo:

```
In [29]: df
Out[29]:
      a        b      c
0  Ivan   Jayesh  James
1   Jan  Jaaaaas    Bob

In [30]: df = df.replace(['^J.*s$','Bo.*'],['James Mcree','Bobby'], regex=True)

In [31]: df
Out[31]:
      a            b            c
0  Ivan       Jayesh  James Mcree
1   Jan  James Mcree        Bobby
```

`'^J.*s$'` - is a RegEx which means find a string beginning with `J` then any number of any characters following by `s`

Special RegEx symbols:

`^` - beginning of the string

`$` - end of the string

Here is an online service which explains RegEx's: https://regex101.com/r/Uu8bUV/1

Comment: Yeah this worked, what are the special characters in ['^J.*s$','Bo.*'] doing can you explain them I have a good idea of what they are doing but would like to see if my understanding is correct